# :remote form with multiple submit buttons

Tags: ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't seem to get a `:remote` form with multiple submit controls to work under Rails 3. The following code:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'debug'}, {:remote => true}) do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Foo" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Bar" %>
<% end %>
```

Produces a form with two buttons, but the resulting AJAX POST doesn't contain a `commit` parameter to say which one was pressed. If I leave `:remote => true` out, the normal POST does contain the `commit` parameter.

Is there any way to make this work, or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing about, I think I've found a solution.

The problem is that `rails.js` uses `serializeArray()` on the `form` element containing the clicked `submit` control; but the form's serialized data doesn't contain that control. However, JQuery or Javascript is keeping track of the original event in the call-chain, which was technically a "submit" event on the appropriate control.

So I've edited rails.js as follows:

```
callRemote: function (e) {   /* Note - new parameter e */
            var el      = this,
                method  = el.attr('method') || el.attr('data-method') || 'GET',
                url     = el.attr('action') || el.attr('href'),
                dataType  = el.attr('data-type')  || 'script';

            if (url === undefined) {
              throw "No URL specified for remote call (action or href must be present).";
            } else {
                if (el.triggerAndReturn('ajax:before')) {
                    var data = el.is('form') ? el.serializeArray() : [];
                    /********************/
                    /* Note new if-test */
                    /********************/
                    if (e)
                    {
                        data.push({name: e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.name,
                        value: e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.value})
                    }
                    /* Function continues as before */
```

... and further down ...

```
$('form[data-remote]').live('submit', function (e) {
    $(this).callRemote(e);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This has the effect of adding in the name-value pair of the clicked button before firing off the AJAX.

I'm a bit new to Javascript, so do let me know if any of this is horrendously wrong!

Comment: This is now the subject of a Lighthouse ticket: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6001

Answer (score 1):

I tried your solution and it worked for Firefox, but then the application did not work any more for IE and Safari. Now I found another solution: Simply putting the value of the submit button into a hidden input field by a small javascript.

```
<input id="selected_button" type="hidden" name="commit" value=""/>
<script>
  function identify_button( el ) {
    window.document.getElementById( 'selected_button' ).value = el.value;
  }
</script>
<input class="button"
       type="submit"
       name="commit"
       value="Save"
       onclick="identify_button( this )" );"
/>
<input class="button"
       type="submit"
       name="commit"
       value="OK"
       onclick="identify_button( this )" );"
/>
```